# Antrl visitor on a grammar with compiler directive

Tags: antlr4, visitor-pattern

I try to get compiler directive in a verilog parser which give me the true file name/path and the true current line in the non-preprocessed file.

Verilog language needs a preprocessing pass I have, but during the visit I have to know the current file name (which can't change by the `include directive) and so the true current line in the non-preprocessed file .

The preprocessing part add the verilog directive *`line* which indicates the current file and line.
Then I send the preprocessed buffer to the antlr Lexer, parse and extract all verilog information with a visitor. I have to keep the verilog compiler `line directive in the verilog grammar description:

```
Preprocessing_line  
: '`line ' Decimal_number String Decimal_number '\n' -> channel(2)  
;
```

Now, I don't know how to get this dedicated channel information at any point in the visitor? The target language for this parser is Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `Preprocessing_line` tokens may not have a reliable relation to the parse-tree tokens (different Verilog compilers can be a bit loose about where they inject the reference lines), the easiest solution is to create a temporary index prior to the visitor walk.

That is, after parsing the pre-processed Verilog source, do a quick pass over the entire token stream (`BufferedTokenStream#getTokens`), picking out the `Preprocessing_line` tokens, and building a `current_line -> original_line` index.

Then, in any visited context, examine the underlying token(s) (`ParserRuleContext#getStart`, `#getStop`, `#getSourceInterval`) to find their `current_line` (`Token#getLine`)

Comment: Thanks GRosenberg for your answer. What did you mean by doing a quick pass over the entire token stream ? Just explore the result of the CommonTokenStream ?

Comment: Yes, just a simple for loop over `stream.getTokens()` to find each `Preprocessing_line` token.